# Mapping to columns with symbols in name

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database for records with column names that look like this

> TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorPublicRecordId [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>
> CASE-CAUSE-NBR nvarchar NULL,
>
> FULL-NAME nvarchar NULL,

I am trying to create a C# object which is mapped to this table however I cant use the "-" symbol because the code doesnt like it. Is there a solution to this? The reason why the table has these columns is because it has been imported from a large government database. Should I create another table without these "-" in the headers? And then map the columns during the import stage?

My goal is to create a C# object that can map to the column names with the "-" symbol in it.

```
public class TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorPublicRecord : Entity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorPublicRecordId { get; set; }

    public string CASE-CAUSE-NBR { get; set; }

    public string FULL-NAME { get; set; }
}
```

In the C# code above the attributes are not working because of the "-" symbol.

Comment: Isn't there a `[Column(string ColumnName)]` attribute you can use on properties to map the property name (whatever you choose) to the actual column name in the database? If so, I would just omit the `-` from the property names.

Comment: @Mark C. [Column(string ColumnName)] could you please provide an example in C# code? Imagine that we cant alter the table. The table will continue having those headers. How can I map it out to my C# object, since I know the names have to match in order to be mapped automatically.

Comment: Something similar to `[Column("CASE-CAUSE-NBR")] public string CaseCauseNumber { get; set; }`

Comment: @MarkC. Hey mark thank you you answered this question perfectly. Please submit your answer so I can target it as the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use the Column Name attribute to override using the property name to be identical to the column name in the database.

In your case, this would be:

```
[Column("CASE-CAUSE-NBR")] 
public string CaseCauseNumber { get; set; }
```

Note that this is also possible with the Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorPublicRecord>() 
    .Property(t => t.CaseCauseNumber ) 
    .HasColumnName("CASE-CAUSE-NBR");
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use backtics

```
`TexasBexarCountyMisdemeanorPublicRecordId` [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

`CASE-CAUSE-NBR` nvarchar NULL,

`FULL-NAME`  nvarchar NULL,
```

this should shadow the minus sign to the sql  engine